# PHP/Bootstrap - Repetição até X e depois até Y então inclui nova DIV e continua a repetição

Tags: php, bootstrap-3, foreach, if, for

Estou quebrando a cabeça nesta repetição, como este é minha primeira pergunta, desculpem os erros. :)

Atualmente estou com este bloco de códigos dentro do container:

```
<?php  
 echo '<div class="row">';
            $posts = DBRead('posts', "WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY data DESC");
            if (!$posts)
                echo '<h2>Nenhum post foi encontrado.</h2>';
            else        
                foreach ($posts as $post): {
                    $categ = DBRead('categorias', "WHERE id = '". $post['categoria']."'");
                    $categ = ($categ) ? $categ[0]['titulo'] : 'SEM CATEGORIA |' ;}
            echo '<div class="col-md-2" style="border:1px solid black">';
        ?>      
                <h4>
                    <a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']?>" title="<?php echo $post['titulo']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $post['titulo']; ?>
                    </a>
                </h4>

                <p>
                    por <b><?php echo $post['autor'] ?></b>
                    em <b><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($post['data'])) ?></b> |
                    <b><?php echo $categ ?></b> 
                    Visitas <b><?php echo $post['visitas'] ?></b>
                </p>
<?php  
    echo '</div>';
    endforeach;
?>
```

Meu objetivo é que a cada 6 registros retornados do banco, ele acrescente uma nova div row abaixo e continue a leitura, até que totalize 4 rows, pois depois vou ver como fazer paginação.

Localizei um código aqui no OverFlow, bem parecido com oque eu quero. Adaptei ele a minha realidade, vejam:

```
<?php 
$postLine = 6;
$posts = DBRead('posts', "WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY data DESC");
foreach($posts as $post => $post){ //$posts array com dados do mysql
  $categ = DBRead('categorias', "WHERE id = '". $post['categoria']."'");
  $categ = ($categ) ? $categ[0]['titulo'] : 'SEM CATEGORIA |' ;

if(($post%$postLine==0) || ($post==0)){ //gera linha com base no numero de          items
?>
<div class="row">
<?php } ?>

<div id="conteudo" class="col-md-2 span7 text-center"><!-- START Video         Content -->
    <div class="video_block">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="" alt="produto"/>
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <span class="video_title"><?php echo $post['title'];?></span>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if(($post%$postLine==0) || ($post==0)){?>
```

tem um porem... o primeiro post esta acima dos outros e desalinhado. Poderiam me ajudar?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: O que vc já tentou para fazer esse seu objetivo? Só uma coisa, tira o `{` do final do `foreach` já que esta usando os `:`.  Agora vamos lá, se eu entendi, a cada 6 posts retornados, vc quer fazer a quebra de linha, é isso? Vc vai  precisar colocar dois contadores ai, um para quantidade de posts por linha (6) e um para quantidade de linhas (4).

Comment: Opa! a idéia é que a cada 6 post ele acrescente uma nova div row.
Localizei um código que se enquadra no que eu quero, tentei embutir ele na minha realidade, ele pulou linha certo, após minhas adaptações, veja: